# Inline assembler syntax error

Tags: visual-c++, x86, port, inline-assembly, osdev

I was getting some strange error when I was developing my operating system. I was making an IO driver using `outb` and `inb`. My `outb` function is as follows:

```
static inline void outb(uint16_t port, uint8_t val)
{
    __asm("outb %0, %w1"  //<--Error
        :
        : "a"(val), "Nd"(port));
}
```

I get this error in Visual Studio:

> C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'opcode'; found '('

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error? How do I fix this error? Any suggestions?

Comment: _"VS"_? As in Visual Studio? The code you've posted isn't using Microsoft's syntax for inline assembly. It looks like something intended for GCC.

Comment: Indeed, that is GCC's inline assembly syntax, **not** Visual Studio's. For Visual Studio, I don't think there's a good way to assign specific variables to specific registers, so you might just want to write the whole function in assembly, in an assembly source file.

Comment: When I helped you previously you were using GNU assembler, not Microsoft. As @Michael points out the syntax of inline Visual C++ in VS is quite different from GNU assembler. VC++ doesn't support assembler templates which are are a GCC extension are unavailable in MS products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio's VC++ doesn't support GNU assembler templates available in *GCC*. Since you define `port` as a 16-bit unsigned integer you need to use the the form of [*OUT*](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_222.html) that takes a 16-bit port number. You need to place the 16-bit port number in *DX*. You also have to treat the variable names in the inline assembly as pointers since you are using standard *CDECL* calling convention for your functions. Sample code:

```
static inline void outb(uint16_t port, uint8_t val) {
    __asm
    {
        mov dx, port
        mov al, val
        out dx, al
    } 
}
```

The function `inb` could be done with something like:

```
static inline uint8_t inb(uint16_t port)
{
    uint8_t data;
    __asm
    {
        mov dx, port
        in al, dx
        mov data, al
    }
    return data;
}
```

This could be simplified by removing the variable `data`, and storing the character read into the variable `port` and then doing `return (uint8_t)port;`. So this would also work:

```
static inline uint8_t inb(uint16_t port)
{
    __asm
    {
        mov dx, port
        in al, dx
        mov byte ptr[port], al   // Need to cast since port is 16-bit variable
    }
    return (uint8_t)port;
}
```

More on using VC++ inline assembly can be found in the Microsoft Developer Network(MSDN) [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hx2csse5.aspx)

Comment: I wouldn't really call that a simplification.

Comment: @immibis Simplifying is subjective, although in this case we are just reusing a variable already available. What I would admit to is that the latter example suffers from poorer code readability.